# Applying software patterns on a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Can someone please explain or point out what are the most common design patterns being used or comes naturally in building a rails app (ie: simple apps with crud and search functionality)?

I mean, Ive been programming in java and used frameworks such as struts, and I was able to apply and identify software patterns such as in creational, structural, and behavioral.

Since I switched to ruby on rails, Ive been trying to understand how can I apply design patterns here....

Comment: Here is an excellent book that you should read it will answer your question [Agile Web Development With Rails](http://komar.bitcheese.net/files/Ruby%20S.,%20Thomas%20D.,%20Heinemeier%20Hansson%20D.%20-%20Agile%20Web%20Development%20with%20Rails,%204th%20Edition,%20Rails%203.2%20%28The%20Pragmatic%20Programmers%29%20-%202011.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> please explain or point out what are the most common design patterns being used or comes naturally in building a rails app

I'm going to start by pointing out the obvious. What comes naturally is the MVC pattern, around which Ruby on Rails is built.

Other than that, Rails does not enforce any particular design patterns, and actually a common beginner mistake is to clutter your views, controllers and models with a multitude of responsibilities, trying to fit everything into the (very limited) MVC universe.

(This also seems to affect the way we write Gems for Rails, as many popular choices tack on to, and adds DSLs your controllers or models.)

That doesn't mean you are restricted to using just models, views and controllers, however. Anything you can do in Ruby, you can also do in Rails.

The popular use of ActiveRecord with Rails will usually prevent you from having a rich domain model, which can, in turn, limit the number of applicable patterns. In particular when working with your models.

Commonly, you will see a rich taxonomy of simple supporting objects, like `service objects`, `form objects`, `query objects`, `policy objects`, `value objects`, etc. All used to encapsulate some perticular behaviour of your application. These objects can implement patterns on their own (for example a `decorator object` implementing the decorator pattern) or be arranged to form common patterns.

For a simple application, this might be all you need--but you can, and should, make use of design patterns where it makes sense in your Rails application.